# Intersection of dictionaries by value ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, search, intersection

I have a dictionary of dictionaries where they have the form of:

```py
"id_1" : { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c8"), 
    "derived_from" : ObjectId("5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c7"), 
    "epsg" : "32723", 
    "active" : True, 
    "name" : "DPA-Time", 
    "range_time_depth" : [ 4648.91338, 5641.545770000001 ], 
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "iline": 6998 
}
```

And I have a dictionary that works like a database query:

```py
{
    '_id': { '$in': ['5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c8','5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c8'] },
    'iline': {'$gte': 6998, '$lte': 7000}
}
```

So, I want to retrieve all dictionaries in the dictionary of dictionaries that have `_id` equals to `'5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c8'` or `'5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c8'` and `'iline'`  between 6998 and 7000.
I know that the intersection method helps in matching dictionaries values, but how can I do that when I want to match a value with a ***range*** of values?

What I've done:

```
def check_correspondence(obj, query):
    for _, value in obj.items():

        if value.keys() & query.keys():
            return True
        else: return False
```

I loop through the dict of dicts mentioned and apply the & operator. However this operator doesn't seem to work with range comparisons, only strict equality.
When I try it, I receive a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: You test for the range, instead of straight equality.  Where are you stuck?  “Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Oh, sure, sorry.I'll edit the question with the code I've already wrote.

Comment: your loop only evaluates once, and then either returns true or false. Also having something like `if [condition]: return True; else: return False` can just be simplified as `return condition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to go through all your keys as you just want to check ids and `iline`.

And careful, `&` and `and` are not the same in python. `&` is a [bit-wise operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm).

```py
objs = {
    "id_1" : { 
        "_id" : "5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c8", 
        "derived_from" : "5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c7", 
        "epsg" : "32723", 
        "active" : True, 
        "name" : "DPA-Time", 
        "range_time_depth" : [ 4648.91338, 5641.545770000001 ], 
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "iline": 6998 
    },
    "id_2" : { 
        "_id" : "5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c9", 
        "derived_from" : "5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c7", 
        "epsg" : "32723", 
        "active" : True, 
        "name" : "DPA-Time", 
        "range_time_depth" : [ 4648.91338, 5641.545770000001 ], 
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "iline": 7002
    } 
}

query_ = {
    '_id': { '$in': ['5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c8','5cefddaae40ed94ea713f7c9'] },
    'iline': {'$gte': 6998, '$lte': 7000}
}

def check_correspondence(obj, query):
    is_in = obj['_id'] in query['_id']['$in']
    is_iline = query['iline']['$lte'] >= obj['iline'] >= query['iline']['$gte']
    
    return is_in and is_iline

for obj_name, obj_ in objs.items():
    print(obj_name, check_correspondence(obj_, query_))
    
# id_1 True
# id_2 False - because 7002 > 7000
```